# Unexpected results when using recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion, permutation

I've just started to get into the world of python and frankly, I'm a little bit confused about the results the following implementation gives me.

It's just a recursive function that should output all of the permutations of a given list. I know there's probably a thousand better ways of doing the same, but this is what I came up with. What strikes me is that the exact same code works just fine in C++; I believe it may have something to do with the way variables are passed in python*, but I'm not sure.

The code:

```
def permut (s, permut_s):
    if not s:
        return permut_s
    if not permut_s:
        last_s = s[-1]
        s.pop (-1)
        permut_s = [[last_s]]
        return permut (s, permut_s)
    new_permut_s = []
    last_s = s[-1]
    for x in range (len (permut_s)):
        aux = permut_s[x]
        aux = [last_s] + aux
        new_permut_s.append (aux)
        for y in range (len (aux) - 1):
            aux_elem = aux[y]
            aux[y] = aux[y + 1]
            aux[y + 1] = aux_elem
            new_permut_s.append (aux)
    s.pop (-1)
    return permut (s, new_permut_s)

def main(s, permut_s):
    print (permut (s, permut_s))

main ([1,2,3], [])
```

*the reason I say this is because doing some prints in between lines shows that before the first non-trivial execution, new_permut_s = [[2,3]], and after, it is [[3,2],[3,2]], when it should be [[2,3],[3,2]]

Thanks a lot !

Comment: When you swap the aux you also swap the same aux you appended to new_permut_s before that. You should make a deepcopy of the list first. (import deepcopy from copy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you append the same list several times. So your modifications affect previous `new_permut_s` elements (as they all can be seen as the same address of the list as the one in `aux`). The simplest solution is the following (see `# THE FIX`):

```
def permut (s, permut_s):
    if not s:
        return permut_s
    if not permut_s:
        last_s = s[-1]
        s.pop (-1)
        permut_s = [[last_s]]
        return permut (s, permut_s)
    new_permut_s = []
    last_s = s[-1]
    for x in range (len (permut_s)):
        aux = permut_s[x]
        aux = [last_s] + aux
        new_permut_s.append (aux)
        for y in range (len (aux) - 1):
            aux = aux[:]  # THE FIX
            aux_elem = aux[y]
            aux[y] = aux[y + 1]
            aux[y + 1] = aux_elem
            new_permut_s.append (aux)
    s.pop (-1)
    return permut (s, new_permut_s)

def main(s, permut_s):
    print (permut (s, permut_s))

main ([1,2,3], [])
```

By `aux = aux[:]` (or `aux = aux[0:len(aux)]`), we take the original list, take its slice (which is always a new object, at least in the standard library) and then assign the slice (a list here) to the same variable.

As for if this copying can be avoided: I don't think so, since lists for all permutations should be independent. Theoretically you can write a class to patch existing lists (such that each instance holds the reference to a "global" list and some local patch, and then the actual value is calculated for an index when it's accessed), or you can merge the code for copying and for swapping (such that you copy several parts of the original list in several steps). But such solutions seem to be overkill for your task.

---

PythonTutor.com helps to debug such issues. Particularly, I used [this "visualization"](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20permut%20%28s,%20permut_s%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20not%20s%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20permut_s%0A%20%20%20%20if%20not%20permut_s%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20last_s%20%3D%20s%5B-1%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20s.pop%20%28-1%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20permut_s%20%3D%20%5B%5Blast_s%5D%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20permut%20%28s,%20permut_s%29%0A%20%20%20%20new_permut_s%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%20%20last_s%20%3D%20s%5B-1%5D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20x%20in%20range%20%28len%20%28permut_s%29%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20aux%20%3D%20permut_s%5Bx%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20aux%20%3D%20%5Blast_s%5D%20%2B%20aux%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20new_permut_s.append%20%28aux%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20y%20in%20range%20%28len%20%28aux%29%20-%201%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20aux%20%3D%20aux%5B%3A%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20aux_elem%20%3D%20aux%5By%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20aux%5By%5D%20%3D%20aux%5By%20%2B%201%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20aux%5By%20%2B%201%5D%20%3D%20aux_elem%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20new_permut_s.append%20%28aux%29%0A%20%20%20%20s.pop%20%28-1%29%0A%20%20%20%20return%20permut%20%28s,%20new_permut_s%29%0A%0Adef%20main%28s,%20permut_s%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20print%20%28permut%20%28s,%20permut_s%29%29%0A%0Amain%20%28%5B1,2%5D,%20%5B%5D%29&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) to debug your code.

In the REPL, such checks are useful:

```
>>> out = permut([1,2,3], [])
>>> out[0] is out[1]
True
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to append somethin as a "copy" to avoid this issue? And could you clarify what aux = aux[:] does?

Comment: aux = aux[:] just makes a shallow copy. So, the returned permutations in the end will contain values which all point to the same object. For some usages this would be problematic.

Comment: @HielkeWalinga A permutation is (by definition) a rearrangement of existing elements themselves ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation), [2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/permutation)) rather than their copies. So deep copying is not only always slower, but it's also functionally incorrect for permutations (if it's not equivalent to shallow copying). If the goal were to get not permutations but something similar, then deep copying might be OK.

Comment: @KirillBulygin Okay, good to know. I checked, and the one from itertools is also implemented with shallow copying.

Answer (score 0):

Forget all the permutations you can use:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.permutations([1, 2, 3]))
```

"Don't reinvent the wheel" is one of the best adages in programming.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not that I want to reinvent anything or use this function in any production. As I said, I'm new to python and just trying out stuff, and knowing why this does not work might help me, and possibly others, to stop making the same mistake in real case scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You are appending shallow copies to your output. Use this:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def permut (s, permut_s):
    print(s)
    print(permut_s)
    if not s:
        return permut_s
    if not permut_s:
        last_s = s[-1]
        s.pop (-1)
        permut_s = [[last_s]]
        return permut (s, permut_s)
    new_permut_s = []
    last_s = s[-1]
    for x in range (len (permut_s)):
        aux = permut_s[x]
        aux = [last_s] + aux
        new_permut_s.append (deepcopy(aux))
        for y in range (len (aux) - 1):
            aux_elem = aux[y]
            aux[y] = aux[y + 1]
            aux[y + 1] = aux_elem
            new_permut_s.append (deepcopy(aux))
    print("new")
    print(new_permut_s)
    s.pop (-1)
    return permut (s, new_permut_s)

def main(s, permut_s):
    print (permut (s, permut_s))

main ([1,2,3], [])
```